# Systemd timer for a bound service restarts the service it is bound to

Tags: service, systemd, system-administration

I have two systemd services `a` and `b`, where `b` is "After" and "BindsTo" `a`, and `b` is a short command that is launched every minute with a systemd timer.

Heres my config:

```
$ cat /systemd/a.service
[Unit]
After=foo
BindsTo=foo

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/a/bin/a
Group=lev
User=lev
Restart=Always
WorkingDirectory=/opt/a

$ cat /systemd/b.service
[Unit]
After=a
BindsTo=a

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/b/bin/b
Group=lev
User=lev
WorkingDirectory=/opt/b

$ cat /systemd/b.timer
[Unit]

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/1:00
```

When I run `sudo systemctl stop a`, service `a` is indeed stopped, but then it is started back up at the top of the next minute when the timer for service `b` runs `b`

The systemd documentation states that `BindsTo`

> declares that if the unit bound to is stopped, this unit will be stopped too.

(https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#BindsTo=)

I expect that by stopping `a`, `b` will also be stopped, and the timer disabled. This is not the case. Can you help explain why the `b` timer restarts not only `b` (which should fail), but also `a`?

Can you also help me edit these services such that:

- on boot, a is started first, then b is started
- when I `sudo systemctl stop a`, `b`'s timer does not run
- when I `sudo systemctl start a`, `b`'s timer begins running again

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the simplest units that meet your constraints:

`test-a.service`

```
[Service]              
ExecStart=sleep 3600  # long-running command
```

`test-b.service`

```
[Service]     
ExecStart=date  # short command
```

`test-b.timer`

```
[Unit]                                
After=test-a.service
BindsTo=test-a.service   # makes test-b.timer stop when test-a.service stops
                                      
[Timer]                                           
OnCalendar=* *-*-* *:*:00             
                                      
[Install]                             
WantedBy=test-a.service  # makes test-b.timer start when test-a.service starts
```

Don't forget to

- `systemctl daemon-reload`
- `systemctl disable test-b.timer`
- `systemctl enable test-b.timer`
  To apply the changes in the `[Install]` section.

Explanations:

- what you want is to bind `a.service` with `b.timer`, not `b.service`
- `b.service` is only a short command, and `systemctl start b.service` will only run the command, not start the associated timer
- only `systemctl start b.timer` will start the timer
- The `WantedBy` tells systemd to start `test-b.timer` when `test-a.service` starts
- The `BindsTo` tells `test-b.timer` to stop when test-a.service stops
- The `After` only ensures that `test-b.timer` is not started at the same time than `test-a.service`: it will force systemd to start `test-b.timer` *after* `test-a.service` has finished starting.

About the behaviour you observed:

- When you stopped your `a.service`, the `b.timer` was still active and it tried starting `b.service` to run its short command. Since your `b.service` specified `BindsTo=a.service`, systemd thought that `b.service` required `a.service` to be started also, and effectively restarted `a.service` for `b.service` to run correctly.

Comment: Thanks @duthils -  I was also suspecting that I needed a `BindsTo` on the timer but I couldn't find any documentation indicating that timers actually support `BindsTo`. Did you try this yourself and does it work? I will spend some time this week trying it as well.

Comment: I did try it, and the timer was correctly started  and stopped at the same time than the bound service. As far as systemd is concerned, timers and services are both units and every setting in the `[Unit]` section is applicable to any unit.

Answer (score -1):

I could be mistaken, but I believe that the "Restart=Always" option is the reason that the service named a is started and hence why the service named b is not subsequently stopped.

The man page for systemd.service states if this option is set to always

> the service will be restarted regardless of whether it exited cleanly
> or not, got terminated abnormally by a signal, or hit a timeout.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=

So even though you are stopping the service, this option is starting it again.

You can test this by running the following commands. Since you have service "b" on a one minute timer, I would run the stop command at 10 seconds after the top of the minute (i.e. 10:00:10). Then I would run the status command 20 seconds later and see if the service has been restarted.

sudo systemctl stop a
sudo systemctl status a b

Comment: See in your linked documentation: `As exceptions to the setting above, the service will not be restarted if ... the service is stopped with systemctl stop or an equivalent operation`